# Sort table by Weeks Days Hours Minutes

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I'm trying to let my users sort the table on my page by the different columns in it.
i use a jQuery plugin that does that for names, dates, numbers ect'

my problem is that one of the columns (the most important one) is: time length for example:

```
3 days
2 weeks 5 days 4 hours 20 minutes
3 days 2 hours
10 hours
```

how can i sort this?

[*i use this plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

[*it allows adding custom sorters here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)

Comment: My approach would be to add a data-attribute to your column which contains the time length in seconds: `<td data-seconds="259200">3 days</td>`, but TableSorter just passes (string)'3 days' to the `format()` method, which is a bit flawed if you ask me. You could fork the plugin to pass the entire element to the `format()` method.

Comment: Whenever I sort by date, I store date as the period elapsed since the epoch. I then convert this integer to a human-readable date for display. If you store the elapsed time as the number of seconds and then convert to the format you've shown for display, this would be trivial. Failing that, to use the same idea that the custom sorters employ, return the # of secs the period represents in the `format` function of your custom-sorter. Simply grab the number and the following word to determine the scaling factor. minutes * 60, hours * 3600, days * 86,400, weeks * 604,800.